# Assign CssClass to LinkButton in MasterPage

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, master-pages

I have some CSS that controls my [asp:LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) hyperlinks, and I want to find out how I can set the [WebControl's CssClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx) property for the current page whenever the MasterPage loads.

These [asp:LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) hyperlinks on the [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx) are contained in a list:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li class="sprite">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton1" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/linkButton1.aspx">
      <span>link 1</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li class="sprite">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton2" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/linkButton2.aspx">
      <span>link 2</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
  <li class="sprite">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton3" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/linkButton3.aspx">
      <span>link 3</span>
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage.aspx) I have tried to set the CssClass using the Page_Load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!IsPostBack) {
    linkButton1.CssClass = "";
    linkButton2.CssClass = "";
    linkButton3.CssClass = "";
    string linkButtonID = Request.RawUrl;
    if (-1 < linkButtonID.IndexOf("linkButton2")) {
      linkButton2.CssClass = "active";
    } else if (-1 < linkButtonID.IndexOf("linkButton3")) {
      linkButton3.CssClass = "active";
    } else {
      linkButton1.CssClass = "active"; // default
    }
  }
}
```

My `CssClass="active"` does not appear to ever be set, and looking at the page source quickly verifies that none of my LinkButton controls has the CssClass property set.

Since this is hard to visualize, I've put together a jsFiddle. The site does not support ASP, but it may help you visualize what I am trying to accomplish:

http://jsfiddle.net/jp2code/kZQwC/

How would I get my Active Page to set the CssClass?

Comment: Move your code to the Page_Init event and let me know if that solves the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assign the class in `!IsPostBack` I am afraid that your url at that time is not having linkButton1, linkButton2 or linkButton3.

You take the `class assignment code out of the if condition` and check if you that those condition executed and getting the class.

Change

```
if (!IsPostBack) {
    linkButton1.CssClass = "";
    linkButton2.CssClass = "";
    linkButton3.CssClass = "";
    string linkButtonID = Request.RawUrl;
    if (-1 < linkButtonID.IndexOf("linkButton2")) {
      linkButton2.CssClass = "active";
    } else if (-1 < linkButtonID.IndexOf("linkButton3")) {
      linkButton3.CssClass = "active";
    } else {
      linkButton1.CssClass = "active"; // default
    }
}
```

To

```
linkButton1.CssClass = "";
linkButton2.CssClass = "";
linkButton3.CssClass = "";
string linkButtonID = Request.RawUrl;
if (-1 < linkButtonID.IndexOf("linkButton2")) {
  linkButton2.CssClass = "active";
} else if (-1 < linkButtonID.IndexOf("linkButton3")) {
  linkButton3.CssClass = "active";
} else {
  linkButton1.CssClass = "active"; // default
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry it took me so long to accept the answer, but I had to wait until I was able rebuild/publish the code to check it.